# Jump to (or get position of) any kind of parent brace

Tags: cursor, jump

I am within a vimscript, and I want jump (or get the position of) the beginning of the current parent brace, how can I make this happen?

Imagine the following example (the cursor is represented by `|`):

```
  (a   &&   (b && c)   &&   | (d && e))     <- For parentheses
  [a   &&   [b && c]   &&   | [d && e]]     <- For square brackets
  {a   &&   {b && c}   &&   | {d && e}}     <- For curly braces
  <a   &&   <b && c>   &&   | <d && e>>     <- For angle brackets
  ^                         ^
parent (jump here)        cursor
```

I know that there are the `[{` and `[(` commands, but they only jump to a `{` and `(`, and not to `[` and `<`. Also I need some kind of way to jump to any parent bracket, not a specific type of one.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the concrete scenario that leads to this problem? Why do you need to jump to the parent bracket at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is provided by standard "matchit" plugin (if running Vim make sure you've enabled it with `packadd matchit`).

Press <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>%</kbd> to get to the previous unmatched bracket. Don't forget to add `<` and `>` to `:h 'matchpairs'` as it's not the default.

Read `:h matchit` for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use

```
call searchpair('<', '', '>', 'bW')
```

To search for arbitrary pairings.